# SVG path mask not working

Tags: svg, mask

According to example of [this tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask)  I want to mask my icon (black and white) instead of text in this tutorial. but right side of icon is still dark. how can I make left side of my icon **black stroke** and right side of icon goes **white stroke**?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="41px" height="50px" viewbox="-3 -3 40 48">

  <defs>
    <mask id="myMask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        x="0" y="0" width="18" height="50">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="15" height="50" fill="white"/>
    </mask>

  <path id="fire-icon" d="m 25.55134,17.573125 c 0.647761,1.273107 1.136636,2.596633 1.344412,4.021007 0.21999,1.47479 0.13444,2.924371 -0.342217,4.348739 -0.427768,1.273111 -1.124413,2.382358 -2.004391,3.378155 -0.977758,1.096637 -2.114394,1.991591 -3.348802,2.773105 -0.183328,0.113445 -0.366658,0.226895 -0.57443,0.365546 1.429964,-3.214282 1.686623,-5.760501 0.366659,-8.924365 -0.904421,-2.155462 -2.395495,-3.743696 -3.519909,-4.4874 0,0 0.305545,3.655466 -2.248829,5.9874 0.391098,-1.184876 -0.672208,-2.31933 -0.672208,-2.31933 -0.31777,1.386549 -0.8922,1.651268 -1.662178,2.836135 -0.366658,0.567227 -0.708873,1.159666 -0.941085,1.802516 -0.342214,0.970596 -0.403325,1.953785 -0.207778,2.96219 0.134444,0.668067 0.342218,1.310925 0.63554,1.941174 0.02446,0.05042 0.04889,0.113449 0.08556,0.226893 C 12.156129,32.308418 11.899468,32.169763 11.655035,31.993294 10.921719,31.463881 10.163961,30.959677 9.467313,30.37985 8.5628918,29.623547 7.8173555,28.715982 7.3284794,27.619344 7.0351536,26.951277 6.8640469,26.245395 6.8151593,25.514301 c -0.097775,-1.65126 0.2933257,-3.201685 0.9899743,-4.676472 0.5010979,-1.071427 0.9777525,-2.142852 1.4544067,-3.226887 0.1344411,-0.31513 0.2199942,-0.66807 0.3055478,-1.008411 0.085554,-0.327726 0.1344412,-0.668063 0.1955503,-1.033609 0.9777516,0.46639 1.4544056,2.521009 0.9044216,3.857144 0.02444,0 0.03666,0 0.06111,0 0.232216,-0.302517 0.464431,-0.605039 0.696652,-0.907563 0.977751,-1.323526 1.869945,-2.684872 2.566595,-4.184872 0.623316,-1.34874 1.099973,-2.735295 1.185527,-4.247902 0.02445,-0.5294123 -0.02445,-1.0714263 -0.03667,-1.6008383 0.01223,0 0.02445,0 0.03667,0 0.65998,0.315125 1.307741,0.680673 1.882172,1.134457 1.014423,0.8193243 1.857728,1.7899163 2.566601,2.8991563 0.892198,1.411766 1.515512,2.936975 1.955505,4.550418 0.01223,0.06302 0.03667,0.126055 0.06111,0.214286 1.344407,-1.210083 0.513317,-4.172266 0.501096,-4.222688 -0.02445,-0.0252 2.261053,2.029411 3.409911,4.512605 z"
  fill="none" stroke="#303233" stroke-width="1.3" />
  </defs>

  <!-- Draw black rectangle in the background -->
  <rect x="18" y="0" width="15" height="50" fill="#000" />
  
  <!-- Draw the text string twice. First, the white text without mask.
       Second, the black text with the mask applied-->
  <use xlink:href="#fire-icon" stroke="white"/>
  <use xlink:href="#fire-icon" stroke="black" mask="url(#myMask)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The mask works, expecting the stroke property on the use element to have an effect is your real problem.

Comment: @RobertLongson  can you correct my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no mask issue. The stroke on the path overrides the stroke on the use element, so in the question there are two grey (#303233) stroked paths. Removing the path stroke atribute allows the use to set one.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="41px" height="50px" viewbox="-3 -3 40 48">

  <defs>
    <mask id="myMask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        x="0" y="0" width="18" height="50">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="15" height="50" fill="white"/>
    </mask>

  <path id="fire-icon" d="m 25.55134,17.573125 c 0.647761,1.273107 1.136636,2.596633 1.344412,4.021007 0.21999,1.47479 0.13444,2.924371 -0.342217,4.348739 -0.427768,1.273111 -1.124413,2.382358 -2.004391,3.378155 -0.977758,1.096637 -2.114394,1.991591 -3.348802,2.773105 -0.183328,0.113445 -0.366658,0.226895 -0.57443,0.365546 1.429964,-3.214282 1.686623,-5.760501 0.366659,-8.924365 -0.904421,-2.155462 -2.395495,-3.743696 -3.519909,-4.4874 0,0 0.305545,3.655466 -2.248829,5.9874 0.391098,-1.184876 -0.672208,-2.31933 -0.672208,-2.31933 -0.31777,1.386549 -0.8922,1.651268 -1.662178,2.836135 -0.366658,0.567227 -0.708873,1.159666 -0.941085,1.802516 -0.342214,0.970596 -0.403325,1.953785 -0.207778,2.96219 0.134444,0.668067 0.342218,1.310925 0.63554,1.941174 0.02446,0.05042 0.04889,0.113449 0.08556,0.226893 C 12.156129,32.308418 11.899468,32.169763 11.655035,31.993294 10.921719,31.463881 10.163961,30.959677 9.467313,30.37985 8.5628918,29.623547 7.8173555,28.715982 7.3284794,27.619344 7.0351536,26.951277 6.8640469,26.245395 6.8151593,25.514301 c -0.097775,-1.65126 0.2933257,-3.201685 0.9899743,-4.676472 0.5010979,-1.071427 0.9777525,-2.142852 1.4544067,-3.226887 0.1344411,-0.31513 0.2199942,-0.66807 0.3055478,-1.008411 0.085554,-0.327726 0.1344412,-0.668063 0.1955503,-1.033609 0.9777516,0.46639 1.4544056,2.521009 0.9044216,3.857144 0.02444,0 0.03666,0 0.06111,0 0.232216,-0.302517 0.464431,-0.605039 0.696652,-0.907563 0.977751,-1.323526 1.869945,-2.684872 2.566595,-4.184872 0.623316,-1.34874 1.099973,-2.735295 1.185527,-4.247902 0.02445,-0.5294123 -0.02445,-1.0714263 -0.03667,-1.6008383 0.01223,0 0.02445,0 0.03667,0 0.65998,0.315125 1.307741,0.680673 1.882172,1.134457 1.014423,0.8193243 1.857728,1.7899163 2.566601,2.8991563 0.892198,1.411766 1.515512,2.936975 1.955505,4.550418 0.01223,0.06302 0.03667,0.126055 0.06111,0.214286 1.344407,-1.210083 0.513317,-4.172266 0.501096,-4.222688 -0.02445,-0.0252 2.261053,2.029411 3.409911,4.512605 z"
  fill="none" stroke-width="1.3" />
  </defs>

  <!-- Draw black rectangle in the background -->
  <rect x="18" y="0" width="15" height="50" fill="#000" />
  
  <!-- Draw the text string twice. First, the white text without mask.
       Second, the black text with the mask applied-->
  <use xlink:href="#fire-icon" stroke="white"/>
  <use xlink:href="#fire-icon" stroke="black" mask="url(#myMask)"/>
</svg>
```